# Is the set of compact operators closed with the strong topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, operator-theory, compactness

It is well-known that the space of compact operators over Banach spaces is closed within the norm topology.
My question:

Let $X$ be a Banach space.

Considering the strong topology (defined by seminorms) on $\mathcal{L}(X)$  i.e., $\{p_x(T):=Tx  \text{ for all } T\in \mathcal{L}(X),\, x\in X  \}$. Do we still have the same result over the strong topology.

$\textbf{Question}$:

$(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of compact operators which converges strongly to $T\in \mathcal{L}(X)$, is $T$ compact ?

Comment: Have you thought about the case where the $T_n$ are 'approximation' operators? (e.g. $T_nx = (x_1,\dots,x_n,0,0,\dots)$ on $l^p$)

Comment: On Hilbert space *every* bounded operator is a strong limit of a sequence of compact operators.

Comment: The in the two previously mentioned examples one has that every operator is the limit of a sequence of operators with finite-dimensional range (called *finite-rank operators*), which are *a fortiori* compact operators. In fact the set of finite-rank operators is dense $\mathcal{L}(X)$ in the strong topology, but there cannot be a *sequence* of finite-rank operators approximating the identity in the strong topology unless the space $E$ has the *bounded approximation property*, which not all separable Banach spaces have, but is implied by the existence of a Schauder basis.